# Is there a way to enable MySQL to explain syntax error in more details?

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL only gives an unhelpful error message when it encounters a grammar or syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near .......

Is there any way to let MySQL to explain syntax error (e.g. expecting closing parenthesis, illegal expression, etc) in details?

Comment: It's actually pretty helpful, but I see your point.

Comment: A syntax error occurs at the spot when the first unexpected "token" is found, so the actual error should be found a few characters earlier. Reading the manual thoroughly is your only way out otherwise :)

Comment: thank you.. sometimes I make a mistake in function call such as `ifnull(sum(margin, 0))` rather than `ifnull(sum(margin), 0)`, mysql tells me that it is a 'syntax error', i wish it could be more helpful and tell me that sum takes only one parameter.

Comment: I'm sure if they had code to give detailed errors it would be enabled by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is - no. All server errors messages and their codes are listed in the documentation.

[Server Error Codes and Messages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html).

From the documentation - *For error checking, use error codes, not error messages. Error messages do not change often, but it is possible.*

About the syntax errors: if there are no more specific error codes, then you get Error: 1149 -  *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax...*

---

As a work around: You can view all syntax errors in dbForge Studio for MySQL. Create new SQL document and write some code, or just open SQL-file, automatic SQL syntax check will highlight errors in the code.

[Automatic SQL syntax check](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/sqlmanagement.html#syntax_check) feature.

This feature is available in Professional and Enterprise editions, but you can try it on trial version.